# Reboot and poweroff 'destructive' on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, reboot, systemctl

When I try to reboot or turn off my laptop, it doesn't work. After investigating a little further:

```
$ systemctl status reboot.target
● reboot.target - Reboot
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/reboot.target; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

reboot is disabled. However, trying to enable it with `systemctl enable reboot.target` results in this output:
`Failed to execute operation: File exists`

After running `reboot`, I get the following error:

```
Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
```

I have no idea what to do; for now I'll just force poweroff, but I'd like to be able to use the reboot and shutdown functionality without cutting power every time I want to turn it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in `man systemctl`, "enabling" a service typically means that you want it to run at boot. If the "reboot" target was enabled, you would be instructing your laptop to be rebooted as part of the boot process. That's probably not what you want.

In `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, set `Storage=persistent`.

Then:

```
 systemctl daemon-reload
```

After your next failed `sudo reboot`, check the contents of your systemd journal file to see if you can find something hanging during shutdown.

Comment: I tried this fix, but it still returns the same message when I try to reboot and systemctl status of reboot.target is still the same, disabled

Comment: As I mentioned, the reboot command is not supposed to be "enabled". Enabling it would cause a boot loop.